# When using the UIImagePickerController in iOS4 to pick from the photo library can you start w/newest first?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

Is there a way to show the UIImagePickerController photo library interface such that when it comes up it starts at the bottom of the library which is where the newest images are in iOS4?  Apparently this is how it worked in 3.x.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the answer here is **no**.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your sourceType from SavedPhotoAlbums to PhotoLibrary:

```
imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
```

After selecting the desired album, the next photo selection view will show the most recent images at the bottom.

However, this adds an additional step, since users need to select an album before viewing the photos.  This works for the Camera Roll, but synced albums still show photos at the top.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with iOS dev, but looking at the doc for this @ Apple: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html

I don't see any way you can do this in one go.

Did you try simply scrolling down after loading the image picker? Or is that not possible?

Sorry, just throwing ideas out there.

Cheers,

Comment: Yea I can't see any indication that its possible either.  Currently you can just scroll down but a user pointed out that back in 3.1x you started at newest 1st and was wondering if this was a setting I could toggle.

Comment: Ye that would be nice to know.

Ah well, maybe you'll be lucky if somebody else knows :)